# Cannot add ManagedPolicy to the lambda that is created in the same stack

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cdk

I'm new to AWS CDK and I'm trying to set up lambda with few AWS managed policies.

Lambda configuration,

```
this.lambdaFunction = new Function(this, 'LambdaName', {
      functionName: 'LambdaName',
      description: `Timestamp: ${new Date().toISOString()} `,
      code: ...,
      handler: '...',
      memorySize: 512,
      timeout: Duration.seconds(30),
      vpc: ...,
      runtime: Runtime.PYTHON_3_8,
    });
```

I want to add `AmazonRedshiftDataFullAccess` ManagedPolicy to lambda role but couldn't find out a way to do it as `addToRolePolicy` supports only the `PolicyStatement` and not `ManagedPolicy`.

Tried something as following, it errored out saying role may be undefined.

```
this.lambdaFunction.role
        .addManagedPolicy(ManagedPolicy.fromAwsManagedPolicyName("service-role/AmazonRedshiftDataFullAccess"));
```

Could anyone help me understand what is the right way to add a ManagedPolicy to the default role that gets created with the lambda function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okay I have made a couple of mistakes,

- It is `AmazonRedshiftDataFullAccess`, not `service-role/AmazonRedshiftDataFullAccess`
- As the role is optional here, I should have done **Optional Chaining** (?.)

The following worked for me,

```
this.lambdaFunction.role
        ?.addManagedPolicy(ManagedPolicy.fromAwsManagedPolicyName("AmazonRedshiftDataFullAccess"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Its a 3 step process :-

- You need to first create role for lambda.
- create lambda and attach role to lambda.
- add aws managed( make sure its correct name )  policy to lambda.

example

```
    const myRole = new iam.Role(this, 'My Role', {
  assumedBy: new iam.ServicePrincipal('lambda.amazonaws.com'),
  });

  const fn = new lambda.Function(this, 'MyFunction', {
  runtime: lambda.Runtime.NODEJS_16_X,
  handler: 'index.handler',
  code: lambda.Code.fromAsset(path.join(__dirname, 'lambda-handler')),
  role: myRole, // user-provided role
  });

  myRole.addManagedPolicy(iam.ManagedPolicy.fromAwsManagedPolicyName("AmazonRedshiftDataFullAccess"));
```